# Powershell: Rename a folder when only partial name is known

Tags: powershell

I need to rename a folder without knowing the full folder name.

For Example  C:\myfolder-2021-5-1  (I know the first part of the folder name)

I would like to rename it to c:\myfolder...  Again, the script wont always know the full folder name.

Edit: I am new to Powershell. I have spent a few hours looking on Google and I don't see examples of people trying to rename a folder using a wildcard. There are very few folder renaming examples that I could find. Most of what I find pertains to renaming files not folders.

I get it people wanting me to "try" first and then ask questions. But, sometimes, especially for us newbies, we don't even know where to start.

I tried using several filename examples and just using a directory name with a wildcard and that did not work.

Don't know what else to say.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Do you mind showing us what you've tried? This is really basic stuff and I'm sure you can do it(:

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show some examples of current and desired names. Explain what the renaming rule is; cover any edge cases if possible.

Comment: That's why I asked for examples of names to be renamed and what the desired new names are. Edge cases are troublesome cases. For example: say, you want to just remove all the numbers and dashes. This is simple in some cases. But: what should happen if you got `myThing-1` and `myThing-2`? There cannot be simultaneously two `myThing`s, so either the renaming rule needs to account this somehow, or the whole process should stop and complain about ambiguous names.

Answer (score 0):

You cant rename a directory if you dont know it's name - thats just not how files and directories work. What you can do is search for a directory that matches your criteria, then you can rename it.

(I'm assuming the reason you dont know the exact name is because its a date, but im also assuming the format of the directory name is consistent)

At its most basic level, this would work for your example:

```
get-childitem -Path c:\ -Directory -Filter "myfolder-????-*-*" | Move-Item -Destination "renamed-myfolder"
```

This will search for directories in C:\ that match the pattern `"myfolder-????-*-*"` - so this pattern would match your example folder `C:\myfolder-2021-5-1`. Then pass that Directory down the pipeline (`|`) into Move-Item where the directory is renamed to `c:\renamed-myfolder`.

This code has some major drawbacks though! It doesnt check if the new name exists before trying to rename the directory so it might fail. Also if more than 1 folder matches the filter only the first rename (`Move-Item`) will succeed. Its upto you to think about these edge cases and add suitable logic to detect/prevent them.

Its a good idea to use `Test-Path` command to check if the destination name already exists or not:

```
if(Test-Path -Path c:\renamed-myfolder){
  throw "ERROR - c:\renamed-myfolder already exists!";
}
```

NOTE: Get-ChildItem filters `*` means "any characters" and `?` means "one character" so `"myfolder-*-*-*"` would also work, but if the year is always 4 digits then use the `????` as its more specific. Ive used the filter `"myfolder-????-*-*"` as im assuming some days/months will be 2 digits like `myfolder-2021-12-12`.